# Determining whether a fixed point of differential equation system is stable or not

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to determine whether the fixed point $(0,0)$ is stable/asymptotically stable or not at all in the next system:
$x'=y$, $y'=-x^n$. I tried to find a Lyapunov function or to linearize (using the differential), without success. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: System is equivalent to the second order equation $x'' = -x^n$. Multiply both sides by $x'$. Aren't these expressions look familiar?

Comment: Actually not so much... Am I missing something simple?

Comment: see this : http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Bernoulli.aspx

Comment: Well, how can Bernoulli Equations family help me here? How do I use this to determine the stability of the fixed point?

Comment: @rapidracim If you want transform this to equation $\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{x^n}{y}$ then it is already separable and can be solved without using Bernoulli equation.

Comment: You are probably missing something like $\frac{d}{dt} \left(\frac{\dot{x}^2}{2} \right) = \dot{x} \ddot{x}$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I actually noticed it but I wasn't sure know how to proceed.
Is the result asymptotically stable for odd numbers and not stable for even numbers?

Comment: That sounds on the right track.  I may post on it when I get out of this rehearsal in an hour or two.

Comment: @RobertLewis It will be very helpful, thank you very much in advance! :)

Comment: Now I feel inspired but I gotta get back to work for awhile!

Comment: I will be waiting:)